# Place text below exposed filter

Tags: 7, views

I have a Drupal view where I would like to enter some text in between 'Exposed Filter' and 'Content' sections. What is the safest of doing this? Attached image shows exact location I need text inserted.

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a custom template for your view.

Go to `/sites/all/themes/YourTheme/templates` folder

create a file called **views-view--[view-name]--[[machine-name]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vsMjX.jpg).tpl.php**

> For example if you view name is "Hello World" and machine name is "block_1"
>
> It would be: `views-view--hello-world--block-1.tpl.php`

Inside your custom template file put:

```
<?php

/**
 * @file
 * Main view template.
 *
 * Variables available:
 * - $classes_array: An array of classes determined in
 *   template_preprocess_views_view(). Default classes are:
 *     .view
 *     .view-[css_name]
 *     .view-id-[view_name]
 *     .view-display-id-[display_name]
 *     .view-dom-id-[dom_id]
 * - $classes: A string version of $classes_array for use in the class attribute
 * - $css_name: A css-safe version of the view name.
 * - $css_class: The user-specified classes names, if any
 * - $header: The view header
 * - $footer: The view footer
 * - $rows: The results of the view query, if any
 * - $empty: The empty text to display if the view is empty
 * - $pager: The pager next/prev links to display, if any
 * - $exposed: Exposed widget form/info to display
 * - $feed_icon: Feed icon to display, if any
 * - $more: A link to view more, if any
 *
 * @ingroup views_templates
 */
?>
<div class="<?php print $classes; ?>">
  <?php print render($title_prefix); ?>
  <?php if ($title): ?>
    <?php print $title; ?>
  <?php endif; ?>
  <?php print render($title_suffix); ?>
  <?php if ($header): ?>
    <div class="view-header">
      <?php print $header; ?>
    </div>
  <?php endif; ?>

  <?php if ($exposed): ?>
    <div class="view-filters">
      <?php print $exposed; ?>
    </div>
  <?php endif; ?>

  HERE <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

  <?php if ($attachment_before): ?>
    <div class="attachment attachment-before">
      <?php print $attachment_before; ?>
    </div>
  <?php endif; ?>

  <?php if ($rows): ?>
    <div class="view-content">
      <?php print $rows; ?>
    </div>
  <?php elseif ($empty): ?>
    <div class="view-empty">
      <?php print $empty; ?>
    </div>
  <?php endif; ?>

  <?php if ($pager): ?>
    <?php print $pager; ?>
  <?php endif; ?>

  <?php if ($attachment_after): ?>
    <div class="attachment attachment-after">
      <?php print $attachment_after; ?>
    </div>
  <?php endif; ?>

  <?php if ($more): ?>
    <?php print $more; ?>
  <?php endif; ?>

  <?php if ($footer): ?>
    <div class="view-footer">
      <?php print $footer; ?>
    </div>
  <?php endif; ?>

  <?php if ($feed_icon): ?>
    <div class="feed-icon">
      <?php print $feed_icon; ?>
    </div>
  <?php endif; ?>

</div><?php /* class view */ ?>
```

> **Note:** The above code is an exact copy of **views-view.tpl.php** located in the `/sites/all/modules/views/theme` folder. I just added
>   the HERE <<<<<<<<<<<<<<< part after the exposed filter php.

**Don't forget to clear/flush the cache to see changes.**

Comment: Thanks again. This works! However I would like to have this text to have some sort of a connection to content area. For an example, assume this text as a description to the table in content area.If the filter outputs zero results, the table disappear but text still appears. How can I link it to content area?

Comment: @user2574948 instead of `HERE <<<<<<<<<` put `<?php if ($rows): ?> HERE <?php endif; ?>` remember to flush the cache to see changes.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone arriving here for Drupal 8/9 (may apply to D7, not sure):

If it is appropriate, you can enter a table caption to describe the table, which is located within the `table` element but above the `thead` and `tbody`. The caption is editable at (Edit) View > Format > (Table) Settings > Caption (in D8.9).